# NSURLSession Delegates split across classes - NSURLSession, NSURLUploadTask, NSURLDownloadTask

Tags: nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I'm in the process of creating an upload/download media feature for my app.  I had the queue working fine for uploads but when I added downloads and the requisite download delegates the upload delegate was called event though the task was to download.
  My initial class structure was a singleton QueueController that had the NSURLSession and delegates (but not download) along with a TransferModel that could hold either the upload or download.
  When I tried to add downloads the callbacks were not working right so I moved to put the transfer related delegates in two sub classes TransferUploadModel and TransferDownloadModel but now my delegates are not firing.

Here is what my method signatures look like:
QueueController:

```
@interface QueueController : NSObject<NSURLSessionDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, weak) NSObject<QueueControllerDelegate>* delegate;
@property(atomic, strong) NSURLSession* session;
@property(nonatomic) NSURLSessionConfiguration* configuration;

+ (QueueController*)sharedInstance;

@end

@implementation QueueController {
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier
completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
//...
}

TransferUploadModel:

    @interface TransferUploadModel : TransferModel <NSURLSessionTaskDelegate,
                                                    NSURLSessionDataDelegate>
    //...

    @end    


//Note TransferModel is a subclass of NSOperation
@implementation TransferUploadModel


- (id)initWithMedia:(MediaItem*)mediaItem_
   withTransferType:(TransferType)transferType_
      andWiths3Path:s3Path_
 andWiths3file_name:s3file_name_
andWithNSURLSession:session {
}


- (void)main {
    //NSOperation override
}



//
// Transfer upload started
//
- (void)uploadMedia {
    /**
     * Fetch signed URL
     */
    AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest *getPreSignedURLRequest = [AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest new];
    getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = BUCKET_NAME;
    getPreSignedURLRequest.key = @"mypic.jpeg";
    getPreSignedURLRequest.HTTPMethod = AWSHTTPMethodPUT;
    getPreSignedURLRequest.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];

    // Important: must set contentType for PUT request
    getPreSignedURLRequest.contentType = self.content_type;
    NSLog(@"headers: %@", getPreSignedURLRequest);

    /**
     * Upload the file
     */
    [[[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder defaultS3PreSignedURLBuilder] getPreSignedURL:getPreSignedURLRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

        if (task.error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
        } else {
            NSURL* presignedURL = task.result;
            NSLog(@"upload presignedURL is: \n%@", presignedURL);

            NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:presignedURL];
            request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
            [request setValue:self.content_type forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

            @try {
                self.nsurlSessionUploadTask = [self.nsurlSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                             fromFile:self.mediaCopyURL];
                [self.nsurlSessionUploadTask resume];
                //
                // Delegates don't fire after this...
                //
            } @catch (NSException* exception) {
                NSLog(@"exception creating upload task: %@", exception);
            }
        }
        return nil;
    }];
}


//
// NSURLSessionDataDelegate : didReceiveData
//
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
          dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"...");
}

//
// Initial response from server with headers
//
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
          dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 completionHandler:
(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"response.description:%@", response.description);
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
}

//
// Upload transfer in progress
//
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionUploadTask *)task
   didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent
    totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent
totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {
    @try {
        NSLog(@"...");
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%s exception: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, exception);
    }
}

//
// Upload transfer completed
//
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
        NSLog(@"...");
} // end URLSession:session:task:error


@end
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that if I moved the NSURLSession into the TransferUploadModel and TransferDownloadModel then the delegates get called.  Since these models are many in a queue I init as so:

```
@implementation TransferUploadModel

static NSURLSession *session = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"transferUploadQueue"];
        configuration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = YES;
        configuration.discretionary = YES;
        session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    });
    self.session = session;
}

//...

@end
```

Thanks,
John